# Integrate $\int\frac{x}{x^3-8}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrate

$$\int\frac{x}{x^3-8}dx$$

I solved this integral by dividing it in partial fractions, than i came in two integrals $I_1,I_2$. Then, partioning $I_2$ into $I_3,I_4$ and partioning $I_4$ into $I_5,I_6$. But it took me so much work even though i got correct answer.

Is there any simple way to solve it?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you display what your $I_n$'s are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recognize

$$\frac{4x}{x^3-8}
= \frac{(x^2+2x+4) -x^2 +2(x-2)}{x^3-8}
= \frac1{x-2} - \frac{x^2}{x^3-8}+\frac2{x^2+2x+4}
$$
and integrate to obtain
$$4\int \frac x{x^3-8}dx=\ln|x-2|-\frac13\ln|x^3-8|+ \frac2{\sqrt3}\tan^{-1}\frac{x+1}{\sqrt3}
$$

Comment: you are completely another level bro always give me special edition approaches,thank you so much and have a good night :)

Comment: @John - my pleasure ...

Comment: @John I agree with you, Quanto is one of the best integral solvers on the site. You can accept his answer if it was the most helpful.

Comment: How did you even manage to split the numerator in such a way?

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{x^3-8}=$$
$$\frac{A}{x-2}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+2x+4}$$

$$A=\frac{2}{12}=\frac 16$$

$$B=-A\;,\;C=2A$$

thus
$$f(x)=A(\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac 12\frac{2x+2-6}{x^2+2x+4})$$

and
$$\int f(x)dx=A(\ln(|x-2|)-\frac 12\ln(|x^2+2x+4|))+3A\int \frac{dx}{(x+1)^2+3}$$

Comment: i am assuming op doesn’t want another partial fractions method; this seems like it leads to the same solution that the op wanted to avoid

Comment: i see now. sorry about that

Comment: @hamam my $I_4$ is this $3A\cdot\int\frac{x}{(x+1)^2+3}dx\:\:$ so i did this$\:\:\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x-2+2}{(x+1)^2)+3}dx$ and evaluated in  $I_4,I_5$

Comment: $I_6=\frac{1}{6\sqrt{3}}\cdot\arctan(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{3}})+C$  cause i carried coefficients before Integral from beginning

Comment: @hamam just added all my $I_n$ and i have same result as you just some coefficients prob. that noticed, now im tryin to shorten my steps as your evaluation  thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Partial fractions will indeed work without the need for too many integrals. We see that
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{x}{x^3 -8} \ dx &= \int \frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{x-2} - \frac{1}{6} \frac{x-2}{x^2 +2x+4}\ dx \\
&= \frac{1}{6} \ln(x-2) - \frac{1}{6} \int  \frac{\frac{1}{2}(2x+2)-3}{x^2 +2x+4}\ dx\\
&\overset{\color{blue}{u=x^2 +2x+4}}= \frac{1}{6} \ln(x-2) - \frac{1}{12} \int  \frac{1}{u}\ du + \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2 +3} \ dx\\
&\overset{\color{blue}{s=x+1}}= \frac{1}{6} \ln(x-2) - \frac{1}{12} \ln(x^2 +2x+4)+ \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{s^2 +(\sqrt{3})^2} \ ds\\
&= \frac{1}{6} \ln(x-2) - \frac{1}{12} \ln(x^2 +2x+4)+ \frac{1}{2} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{3}} \right)}{\sqrt{3}} + C
\end{align*}